# How to use google direction api in ios?

Tags: javascript, ios, google-maps-api-3

I am new in iOS, I want to use the google api direction services, i got the java script on google documentation, i also know how to run the simple java script in iOS using UIWebView, but still am unable to run the script given on google on following link : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#TransitInformation

I dont need to use MapView, I want to access the information only.

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript"

    var directionsDisplay;
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    var map;

    function initialize() {
        directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
        var chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(41.850033, -87.6500523);
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom:7,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            center: chicago
        }
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
        directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
        directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById("directionsPanel"));
    };

    var root = function(diameter) {
        var start = document.getElementById("start").value;
        var end = document.getElementById("end").value;
        var request = {
            origin:start,
            destination:end,
            travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
        };
        directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
                                if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                                directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
                                }
                                });

        return 100;
    };


</script>
</head>

<body>

</body>
</html>
```

for testing i am just returning some value, but it is not giving me output, the function is called, but hangs somewhere in code

Comment: Yes, when i comment all other code, it returns value.i.e. function called but not executing successfully, so can u help me Raj ?

Answer (score 2):

1. This has nothing to do with iOS.If you're building a web application it should run in any browser and in any OS.

2 - You say:

> I dont need to use MapView, I want to access the information only.

...but this is not allowed! You may only use Google Maps Data if you are displaying a map that is publicly accessible. See [**section 9.1 of the TOS**](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#section_9_1) and **10.1.1 (g) ["No Use of Content without a Google Map.](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#section_10_1)**":

Comment: Thanks Marcelo for your valuable comment, but is there any alternate option for this, I want to request to direction service, and want to get transit specific information in response.

Comment: @prabhu, the only **legal option** is to request permission from Google to use their data without displaying a map, but I wouldn't count on obtaining it unless you are a paying business customer.

Comment: and is there any scope to use the UIWebView here ? I used it for executing java script. can it helpful in our case ?

Comment: Thanks again. I am new in development, so i dont knw these things.

Comment: @prabhu, I cannot really answer that question. It all depends on what your objectve is. If you want to build an application that displays a map and it is accessible to the public then everything should be OK, regardless of whether you make it as a web page  on some website, that people can view with any browser, or an app using UIWebView that people can download for free.